# Vue multiselect options from an API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue multiselect and I need my options to come from an api. When I use the example from the official docs it works.

```
import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data () {
    return {
      value: [
        { name: 'Vue.js', language: 'JavaScript' }
      ],
      options: [
        { name: 'Vue.js', language: 'JavaScript' },
        { name: 'Adonis', language: 'JavaScript' },
        { name: 'Rails', language: 'Ruby' },
        { name: 'Sinatra', language: 'Ruby' },
        { name: 'Laravel', language: 'PHP' },
        { name: 'Phoenix', language: 'Elixir' }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But if I replace the options with my data it fails

```
data: function () {
            return {
                value: [],
                options: this.users
            }
        },
methods: {
       getUsers: function () {
            this.$http.get('/api/get/users').then(function (response) {
                    this.users = response.data;
                    this.updateUsers();
                    console.log(this.users)
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                });
            },
            updateUsers: function () {
                this.options = this.users;
            }
        },
        created: function () {
            this.getUsers();
        }
    };
```

I have tried calling the method with `mounted`, `beforeMount` and `beforeCreate` and none of them work. My console shows the following errors:

[image: Vue Errors]

I am sure the issue is with how am passing the options but I don't know how to pass them the right way.

For the template I am just using the default for now:

```
<div>
      <label class="typo__label">Simple select / dropdown</label>
      <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :clear-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true" placeholder="Pick some" label="name" track-by="name"></multiselect>
      <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value  }}</code></pre>
  </div>
```

Comment: try initializing `options` as an empty array: [] , otherwise can you create fiddle of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try  initializing options as an empty array: []

```
data: function () {
        return {
            value: [],
            options: []
        }
    },
```

Later when you get the data from backend, you can populate the data in options, as follows:

```
methods: {
   getUsers: function () {
        this.$http.get('/api/get/users').then( response => {
                this.options = response.data;

                console.log(this.users)
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            });
        },
```

Comment: How will I add the users as options if I initialise it with an empty array

Comment: @PhillisPeters options will be updated when your backend call will return data as I have updated in updated answer.

Comment: To ask another question (though silly) how do I append the values selected to the request that passes to laravel. The `input` tag produced by multiselect doesn't have the `id` and `name` attributes. `<input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select User" class="multiselect__input">`

Comment: no, I can get the selected values successfully but when I click submit, it does not pass the values to the `request`.

Comment: What type of data should the multiselect pass to the `request`? I found a work around to pass the value but its sending it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

In console it's saying prop `'options' expected array got undefined`

mean value to `this.options` not assigning.

Try like this :

create variable outside this.$http request.

```
let self = this;
```

then replace :

`this.options` to `self.options`

This should work.